# How to replace 3 largest values sorted by index in a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace

I have an easy question, but I've been struggling with the answer. I have a DataFrame, from which I want to replace the 3 largest values with their 7 day rolling means, but in index order. So for a DataFrame like this one:

```
Sales
 2
 4
 6
 8
 10
 12
 14
 100
 100
 200
```

I want to replace first the two rows with `100` in `Sales`, and then the row with `200`. I tried the following:

```
df.Sales.replace(df.Sales.nlargest(3).sort_index(),df.Sales.rolling(window=7).mean())
```

But it brings the following error:

> AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'replace'

I know that this works:

```
df.Sales.replace(df.Sales.max(),df.Sales.rolling(window=7).mean())
```

And I could do that 3 times, but I have the problem that it would replace `200` first, and then the others, so it isn't exactly what I need.

I guess something like this would work:

```
for i in df.Sales.nlargest(3).sort_index():
    df.Sales.replace(i, df.Sales.rolling(window=7)
```

But I would rather avoid loops. Is it possible?

EDIT: expected output would be:

```
Sales
 2
 4
 6
 8
 10
 12
 14
 8
 8.86
 9.55
```

In other words, replacing the first 100 with the average from 2 to 14, which is 8. Then replacing the second 100 with the average between 4 through the second 8, which is 8.86, and so on.

Comment: Could you add the expected output?

Comment: @DanielMesejo done

Comment: @RafaelC I think the line is correct. The actual line of code looks like this:
`deporte.Cantidad_Vendida.replace(deporte.Cantidad_Vendida.nlargest(5),deporte.Cantidad_Vendida.rolling(window=7).mean())` which if I'm not mistaken is exactly the same (nlargest equals 5 instead of 3, `df` is `deporte` and `Sales`is `Cantidad_Vendida` )

Comment: What you want is not a rolling windows, the rolling windows uses the values present in the array.

Comment: That's a very good point. So I should take the rolling mean of the shifted value, right?